# Pronunciation when adding -que

Tags: pronunciation, stress, enclitic

Wheelock's Latin says:

> In a word of two syllables the accent always falls on the first
>   syllable: sér-vō, sáe-pe, ní-hil.
>
> In a word of three or more syllables, the accent falls on the next to
>   last syllable (sometimes called the "penult"), if that syllable is
>   long: ser-vā´-re, cōn-sér-vat, for-tū´-na.
>
> Otherwise, the accent falls on the syllable before that (the
>   "antepenult"): mó-ne-ō, pá-tri-a, pe-cū´-ni-a, vó-lu-cris.

And regarding long syllables, it says:

> A syllable is long by nature if it contains a long vowel or a
>   diphthong; a syllable is long by position if it contains a short vowel
>   followed by two or more consonants or by x, which is a double
>   consonant: ks. Otherwise a syllable is short; again, the difference is
>   rather like that between a musical half note and a quarter note.

There is an exception for the last case, as the books says:

> A stop (p, b, t, d, c, g) plus a liquid (l,r) generally count as a
>   single consonant.
>
> Also counted as single consonants are qu and the aspirates ch, ph, th.

So, if those are the rules for accentuation, what happens when in a word, the particle -que is added? For example, the word fīlius has the accent in the antepenult: fílius, but with the particle -que, would that be filiúsque (because the syllable *us* would be long by position) or does the word keep its original accentuation and just adds the sound of que, thus being fíliusque?